# How to stop repeating image

Tags: html, css

no-repeat is also not working.

```css
    .learning-outer-div
    {
    width:100%;
    height:600px; 
    max-height:100%; 
    background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/150);
    background-size: 104% auto;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="learning-outer-div"></div>
```

Comment: What size is the image you are using?

Comment: I made a snippet. Please fix the image to be the size where you have the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need quotes around your url. Then use the `background` instead of `background-image`, because that's the shorthand.

The following code centers the background-image horizontally and vertically. The `background-size` specifies that the image should size to fill (always fill the background).

```
background: url("https://via.placeholder.com/150") no-repeat center center;
background-size: cover; /* size to fill */
```

Answer (score 4):

`background-image` doesn't take a `no-repeat` option.

you'd need `background`

`background: url(../images/banner.jpg) no-repeat;`

or

`background-repeat: no-repeat`

Comment: when using no-repeat background image is invisible.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.learning-outer-div
{
width:100%;
height:600px; 
max-height:100%; 
background-image: url(../images/banner.jpg) no-repeat;
background-size: 104% auto;
}
```

can you try this? thats all...

Comment: Can you add an image from placeholder.com to show the result?